# What If: Weaponized Nuclear Technology Ceases to Work

Tags: warfare, geopolitics, nuclear-weapons

This scenario requires some suspension of disbelief:

*assume that for some unknown reason,  in 2017 weaponized nuclear technology stopped working. All existing nuclear weapons cease to function and it is impossible to build new ones. This occurs globally in an instant. Assume also that it is evident from inspecting the bombs that they aren't going to work, no failed detonations necessary.

What sort of geopolitical fallout would likely occur if there all of a sudden is no such thing as 'Mutually Assured Destruction", and smaller states know they can't be nuked?

I'm looking for what would happen in the time frame of perhaps a year, maybe two.

Comment: How is the change apparent, prior to somebody's failed attempt at a detonation?

Comment: Thats what I was going for; that somehow any country that inspected their weapons would be able to tell its not going to work. I wasn't really worried about how they'd tell and was taking for granted that it'd be knowable. I can modify the question to reflect that.

Comment: MAD is only related to nuclear weapons because that's the current pinnacle of technology. There are many other forms of MAD, such as bioweapons and mass drivers. (The latter is more fun, but a little harder to pull off.)

Comment: As usual in questions of the form "what if this completely impossible thing happened?", the main effect would be theological. It would be definitive proof of a divine power (or a power that might as well be divine), and would cause a profound change in attitudes to religion and in all existing religions.

Comment: I don't see how this is answerable. You suggest that an impossible thing happens, with no explanation, and then want the answerer to tell you what happens next? What if frogs rain from the sky next? That seems just as likely as anything else in this case. Voting to close as 'primarily opinion-based.'

Comment: As an alternative, one might consider what would happen if we simply became unable to *use* nuclear weapons.  Some who want to dig into the "how did this miracle happen?" argument might be more comfortable relaxing the argument to something that could be social (perhaps every single nuclear engineer went mad at the same time, and every one of them put a good sized divot in every nuclear weapon and refused to make more).  Obviously you're looking for political rammifications, not scientific/religious ones, and that alternative might help some avoid getting sidetracked.

Comment: @kingledion for the sake of argument, we could assume that Aliens fired their handwavium anti-nukebomb ray at the planet named "The nuclear negavator" and broadcast the fact to the people of earth.

Comment: ok. Perhaps I'll find a better way to restate the question which will involve less hand-waiving.

Comment: Guess I need to catch up with the century. I thought "well who cares 10,000 ICBM's with conventional explosives would still be MAD" but disarmament seems to have us down to only a few thousand.

Comment: What is special about smaller states in this scenario?  You ignore nuke in the hands of a terrorist (not an organized state)?

Comment: Without nukes to deter conventional wars (their main purpose)...one imagines you would see more conventional wars.

Comment: I disagree with the hold. The nature of WB is there is going to be a lot of opinion, much more than most other SE sites.  I would like this one re-opened.  Several interesting SF stories have as a factor an agent/process/field that interferes with nuclear reactions.  I'll cite S.M.Sterling's Emberverse as a good example.  In that one he plays fast and loose with high pressure chemistry and electricity.  As the series develops it is less SF and more fantasy.  But this is worldbuilding.

Comment: @CortAmmon: are you sure that preventing nuclear detonations is "going mad"?  BTW, most nuclear weapons are not accesible to the engineers who designed them.

Comment: @MikeScott: In fact, several religions would probably claim to be responsible—and there would remain (as before) no way of proving that one of them isn't (as opposed to all aren't) true.

Answer (score 5):

## Not much change

Most nuclear powers are also conventional powers. Smaller states cannot resist them in a conflict, nukes or no nukes. Remember how the UK fought Argentina?

- North Korea has lost an important bargaining chip, but also a bone of contention. Similar for Iran.
- Pakistan vs. India could get interesting.
- The US would still be able to hurt China, but only at a serious price to themselves. The price wouldn't be the loss of a couple of cities any more, but the economic dislocation would hurt both sides.
- Russia would feel a lot less secure and further increase their military spending.

Comment: Israel would probably be dealing with a war, as their "possible" nuclear weapons would be gone and the neighboring Arab nations might actually decide a war was worth a try again. Judging by 1983,1972, 1967 and 1949, probably not.

Comment: @JohnSmith, I doubt that there would be a coordinated action. And without that they have no chance.

Answer (score 3):

You would see rapid realignment of alliances, massive buildups of conventional weapons, cyber warfare tactics, rapid development of new high-yield explosives and economic upheaval, as these new toys would be costly

China would become a greater global power, because military size would be a major consideration again.

Russia would become less of one, as their conventional military is less of a threat than their nuclear arsenal.

Then things would calm down.

A few skirmishes might erupt, but total war is still costly and risky.  Traditional weapons can still lay waste to entire countries and on a scale much larger than historically possible, so mutually assured destruction is not entirely off the table.

Edited to expand a bit on the "calm down" point.

The major powers in the world are heavily vested in international trade and would take a very dim view on small upstart nations hitting them in the wallets with petty wars.

Even without nuclear warheads, conventional weapons have gotten far far deadlier with the advent of the MOAB (Mother Of All Bombs) which can deliver an explosive force equal to the nuke dropped on Hiroshima.  Conventional war is still a very messy thing and not something that many nations would rush into ESPECIALLY since nobody has the nuke any longer.  If A and B go to war then C may sit on the sidelines and wait until one or both are significantly weakened, then strike.

One of the post WWII global strategies was to intertwine as many economies as possible to make any sort of global conflagration less possible due to the economic interests of all involved.

An old saying is that where goods cross borders, soldiers do not.

Comment: Gently disagree that "things would calm down."

Comment: @user535733 thank you for the feedback, I have edited my answer to provide more detail behind my reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

## Everybody will die instantly...

... because if the laws of physics change life as we know it is not possible. This is the problem with physics and life: life is an effect of the laws which govern the behavior of natural phenomena. Life as we know it is a very delicate effect, balanced on a very narrow equilibrium.

## ... But there are loopholes

The first loophole is the always available loophole: you can always move from writing science fiction to writing fairy tales. In fairy tales anything goes, cats can wear boots and talk, nukes can stop working while hemoglobin continues to bind with oxygen and carbon dioxide, *anything*.

If you don't want to switch from science-fiction to fairy tales then you must engineer an acceptable solution.

Engineering, just like politics, is based on compromise. The problem arises because of the strict conditions imposed by the question: (1) all nuclear weapons become defective, (2) this happens instantly, and (3) no more nuclear weapons can be made. Should those conditions be relaxed just a little bit, the situation becomes imaginable. Let us agree that the desactivation of the world's nukes won't be instant, that there may be one or two left, and that building new ones will be possible but it will take quite some time.

Let's say that there is a hidden power, maybe the [Hashshashin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassins) commanded by the [Old Man of the Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashid_ad-Din_Sinan), maybe a reconstructed [International Liaison Department](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Liaison_Department_(Comintern)), maybe a cartel of [private military companies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_military_company), maybe a fictional United Nations Anti-Nuclear Benevolent Action League (UNANBAL), I don't know, who by relentless plotting and planning reaches a position where:

1. They can disable all nuclear weapons in existence.
2. They can prevent building new such weapons for a significant amount of time.

This is hard to do, but literally infinitely easier than ensuring the continuation of life when the laws of the universe change. How could they do it?

- To disable all nuclear weapons they could proceed stepwise:

  1. Convince all nuclear powers to sign a nuclear-weapon reduction treaty, intended to reduce the stockpile to no more than what's needed for [Mutually Assured Distraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_assured_destruction), or, in the case lesser powers, to a level compatible with their lesser status. This will bring the next step within reasonable (that is, not absurdly hard to believe) reach.
  2. Infiltrate [IAEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Energy_Agency), Euratom etc. in order to keep tabs on the so-called "peaceful" applications of atomic power.
  3. Do something with each class of weapons. Those which have launch codes will get their codes changed -- if you want your nuclear codes back please pay one meeeellion Bitcoin in this Paypal account. Those mounted on top of rockets or on torpedoes will get launched in the depths of the ocean. Others will be physically damaged -- hit with a hammer, defaced with permanent marker, something. Do the research, find out in how many classes should nukes be classified, and imagine a way to disable each of them.
- To prevent building new ones they could — corner the market in uranium, tritium, and whatever raw materials are needed — develop a new and enhanced [Stuxnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet) to damage all specialized equipment — kill (in public and in a spectacular way) a few hundred nuclear scientists and engineers and let it be known that whoever works for the criminals attempting to build a new nuclear weapon will suffer the same fate — and so will their families — and their dogs — organize mass demonstrations against the resumption of nuclear arms race (idiots are always aplenty)— arrange with the respective organized crime organizations to ensure that no new nukes are built in exchange for not following the fate of the nuclear scientists and engineers — and so on, you think about it.

## The consequences

The consequences may be thought to be minimal on the geopolitic scale — maybe India will finally feel free to go to war against Pakistan for real, maybe a bellicose Arab League will try again to defeat Israel, maybe Russia will feel an irresistible impulse to attempt to restore the Empire in Central Asia. Small stuff, all considered. But this is a misleading appearance.

In reality, all the powers will need to face the reality that a hidden power had manipulated them into a situation where they no longer have the ultimate deterrent. Or do they? Both Russia and the U.S.A. have, for example, [thermobaric bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermobaric_weapon) which may reach yields "greater than the smallest dial-a-yield nuclear weapons at their lowest settings" (Wikipedia).

However, the (fictional) reality will be that the world now has a very powerful hidden power whose ultimate objectives and capabilities are not known. And who is to say that the said power did not steal or otherwise secure a handful of nukes for its own use? So the only reasonable action path of great and middling powers would be to —

- Form an all-powerful vetting group tasked with ensuring the purity of all Very Important Persons, Important Persons, and Almost Important Persons in the country. They could call it the Holy Inquisition, the Bureau of Personnel, or some other appropriately ominous name.
- Expand the power of the counter-intelligence services, of the secret police, of the counter-organized-crime departments etc.
- Requiring a blood-curling oath of allegiance from every public employee, industrialist, banker, worker, engineer, farmer and lingerie model is optional but wise countries will do it.
- Establish one or more deeply secret closed cities dedicated to weapons development, surveillance equipment development, surveillance data processing and other such activities. The Russians, being the world's best experts in the matter of secret closed cities will make a fortune from consulting services. They can also offer support for establishing the Inquisition and for strengthening the secret police — they have ample experience.

The real question is of course what are the true motives of the UNANBAL, or of the Hashshashin or of the reconstructed International Liaison Department. They have shown that they can materially affect the geostrategic balance. What will they do next? To find out watch the second season of the thrilling series *End of Fission* on your favorite streaming service.

Comment: Suppose you can create a strong nuclear field that decreases the neutron capture cross section highly charged nuclei.  (This lets the sun keep shining -- a Good Thing (tm) It doesn't much of a reduction to make a bomb unworkable without serious re-engineering.  However a subtle enough effect may still allow some times of reactors to continue to work by drawing out the control rods.  The source of the field can either be a clandestine research group, or aliens.

Answer (score 2):

You don't write, what happen to the peaceful applications of the nuclear energy, particularly to the nuclear power plants. Also they cease to work?

If yes, then yes, it would cause such a world-level energy crisis, like a world war. Around 30% of the energy production of the world is going with nuclear energy. A possible, wonder-like explanation would be for that, if

- *simply all fissile material on the Earth suddenly disappears*. In this case, previous (and wanna-be) nuclear powers will start very fast try to get the Uranium somewhere from the space. It would be a perfectly unexplainable event, which would likely catalyze all of the supernatural religions, ideologies and movements. It would also likely catalyze the material efforts what the governments invest into the physics research, because everybody will be curious to some scientific explanation; furthermore nobody will want that the next similar *"change"*, for example, destroy all of our energy producing capacity.
- *somehow the interactions change on a way which make the induced nuclear fission impossible*. Now the problem is that the Sun is driven by (although significantly different) nuclear reactions; it would be probably hard even for a physicist to find such a "re-parametrization" of the natural constants on which the fusion of the Sun behave exactly as it did, while we won't have induced fission any more. It would be a similarly wonder-like demonstration of the [anthropic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropic_principle). In any other cases the Sun would explode on the spot like a supernova, or it would cool down (we would feel its result only around a million years later, until that its internal heat would be enough). Furthermore, currently stable isotopes would be once unstable, while currently unstable isotopoes would be stable. The first will likely result that the Earth explodes like a big nuclear bomb.

If no, thus only the nuclear weapons become suddenly unusable: if nuclear weapons don't work, but nuclear reactors still work, then it would be still possible to create nuclear bombs - but not in their current, in rocket packable sizes, rather large ones, like a nuclear reactor [nuclear reactors can't be built up to be able to induce a nuclear explosion]. These couldn't be transfered by rockets or by planes, at most by... for example, ships.

These would be mainly unusable for strategic weaponry.

---

From that point, probably not too much would change. The "sad" truth is, that nuclear weapons are currently in an outgoing phase, nobody wants to dismantle them, but no real nuclear powers has exploded one since around 20 years. Now consider, for example, the people working on them. How could a nuclear engineer work on nuclear rockets, if he never in his life seen one to explode? If only their old co-workers, on the border of the pension, have only ever seen a real nuclear explosion? How can they be sure that their bombs would really explode on need?

The "sad" answer is, that they don't know. They've a lot of - super-secret - experimental results, they have big serverfarm to simulate explosions, but if you want anything, which really works, you have to test it. And they can't test it.

So, I don't wait too much change.

Oh, wait... also the nuclear deterrent effect would suddenly disappear!

It won't be a problem any more for the U.S., for example, to conquer Russia! (The Russians are so aggressive that they've [put](https://socioecohistory.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/russia_wants_war_look_how_closely_they_put_country_to_our_military_bases.jpg) their country exactly around the peaceful U.S. military bases. ;-) )

...but, also this is not true. All of the major nuclear powers have still large reserves of B(iological) and C(hemical) weapons, and they would still work.

I think, the world would remain around the same. Instead nuclear weapons, the major powers would use maybe larger reserves of chemical and biological ones.

Answer (score -1):

Um, you know we have a lot of ways to destroy all life on the rock, right?  So sorry, we failed to nuke you.  We dropped powdered Plutonium on you instead.   If you feel you died in a less spectacular manner, too bad.

You might be more interested in the premise of Trigger.   What if all gun powder and conventional explosives fail?